# Check whether any values in array match any values in json column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a problem of checking whether any values in an array match any values in json column which contains an array with a name.
suppose i have an array **[25,36,45,52]** and json column is **{"values": [25,24,15]}**.
I want to check whether any values in array match any of values in json column in xampp mysql. please provide a better solution of doing this. [this image show table structure of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV13T.png)

i have 4 tables.

- user
- profile
- profile
- jobs

```sql
user table (id,userid)
jobs table (id,user_id,skill_id)
skill table (id,job_id,)
profile table (id,user_id)
```

now i want to search all jobs that match some or at least one skills.
i have tried with this but this is giving all jobs with out skills filtered.

```php
$jobs = Job::with(['user','profile'])->with(['skills' => function($query){
$query->whereJsonContains('skills->skills',[35]);
}])->where('jobs.is_completed',0);
```

please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i have not tried yet but i am not getting how to do this. please provide some solution

Answer (score 1):

you can use where Clause easily for example you would like to get rows that match skills 35,54:

```
$users = DB::table('table')
                -> whereJsonContains('skills->skills', [35,54])
                ->get();
```

for more details about how to querying json column check official docs :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: But with multiple values it reaches with multiple values like AND condition but I want search Like OR condition. please provide a solution

Comment: if you want complicated where and some advanced filter i advise you using relations with eloquent models feature it's easy to implement

Comment: hello, i did some edit in post. can you please help me now.